# How to change dropdown menu attributes on jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

My problem is that i have 2 dropdowns and I want to change second dropdown by the value of first. For example: if user chooses "Apple" on the first dropdown second dropdown should instantly get "iPhone" and "iPad" options. If client changes his mind and selects "Microsoft" "iPhone" and "iPad" values should be deleted and instead of them there should appear "Windows" and "Office". How can I make it work? Thanks.

**HTML:**

```
<select name="brand" id="brand" onChange="populateSecond(this.value);">
    <option value="">----------------</option>
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="2">Microsoft</option>
</select>
<select id="model">
    <option value="">----------------</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#brand").change(function(populateSecond(id)) {

            if(id == 1){
                $('select[id=model]').append('<option value="a">iPhone</option>');   
                $('select[id=model]').append('<option value="a">iPad</option>');
            }if(id == 2){
                $('select[id=model]').append('<option value="b">Windows</option>');    
                $('select[id=model]').append('<option value="b">Office</option>'); 
            }
    });
});
```

Problem: http://jsfiddle.net/w6E88/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another jQuery way of achieving the functionality you want (commented with explanation)

Added bootstrap class to select element for the looks.

**HTML**

```
<select id="mainCategorySelect" name="mainCategorySelect" class="form-control">
    <option>Select category</option>
</select>

<select id="subCategorySelect" name="subCategorySelect" class="form-control"></select>
```

**JS**

```
// Wait for the dom to be ready
$(function () {

    // For the sake of this example our business and products are arrays
    var businesses = ["Microsoft","Apple"],
        msProducts = ["Microsoft Phone","Microsoft Office","Microsoft Windows 10"],
        appleProducts = ["Apple iPhone","Apple iPad","Apple iPod","Apple iSomething"],

        // Declare variables for the select elements
        mainCategorySelect = $('#mainCategorySelect'),
        subCategorySelect = $('#subCategorySelect');

    // Iterate thorugh businesses and populate the main select element
    for (var i = 0; i < businesses.length; i++) {
        mainCategorySelect.append("<option value='"+businesses[i]+"'>"+businesses[i]+"</option>");
    }

    // using jQuery .on('change')
    mainCategorySelect.on('change', function() {
        // Always clear the sub category select when main select element value is changed
        subCategorySelect.empty();
        // Retrieve the value of the main select element
        var business = $(this).val();
        // if else statement to deside which products to list in the sub category select element
        if (business == "Microsoft") {
            // if Microsoft then iterate through the msProducts array and append the values as option elements to the sub category select element
            for (var i = 0; i < msProducts.length; i++) {
                subCategorySelect.append("<option value='"+msProducts[i]+"'>"+msProducts[i]+"</option>");
            }
        } else if(business == "Apple") {
            // if Apple then iterate through the appleProducts array and append the values as option elements to the sub category select element
            for (var i = 0; i < appleProducts.length; i++) {
                subCategorySelect.append("<option value='"+appleProducts[i]+"'>"+appleProducts[i]+"</option>");
            }
        }
        // When the user changes the value of the sub category select element the do something with it
        subCategorySelect.on('change', function() {
            alert($(this).val());
        });
    });
});
```

And here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kagLhpka/

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `onChange` from the html and do it like this!You are already using Jquery `onchange` no need to give `onChange` to your HTML also if you need the selected value from the first dropdown you could simply use `this.value` to get it and make the necessary changes to your Second DropDown List.

**HTML**

```html
<select name="brand" id="brand">
    <option value="">----------------</option>
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="2">Microsoft</option>
</select>
<select id="model">
    <option value="">----------------</option>
</select>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#brand").change(function() {

       var id=this.value;
        if(id == 1){
             $('#model').html("");
            $('#model').append('<option value="a">iPhone</option>');   
            $('#model').append('<option value="a">iPad</option>');
        }else if(id == 2){
            $('#model').html("");
            $('#model').append('<option value="b">Windows</option>');    
            $('#model').append('<option value="b">Office</option>'); 
        }
        else{
         $('#model').html("");
         $('#model').append('<option value="">----------------</option>')
        }
});
});
```

Comment: The pleasure is all mine :)

Answer (score 1):

You already have `onChange="populateSecond(this.value);"` in your HTML code, no need for the `.change` in JS as well.

You can either define the function `populateSecond` entirely before the first call to it; or use only the jQuery method. I'm giving the jQuery result here only:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#brand").on('change', function (id) {
        if (id == 1) {
            $('select[id=model]').append('<option value="a">iPhone</option>');
            $('select[id=model]').append('<option value="a">iPad</option>');
        } else {
            $('select[id=model]').append('<option value="b">Windows</option>');
            $('select[id=model]').append('<option value="b">Office</option>');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="brand" id="brand">
    <option value="">----------------</option>
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="2">Microsoft</option>
</select>
<select id="model">
    <option value="">----------------</option>
</select>
```

**PS**: I prefer using `.on('change', handler)` method over `.change`.

Comment: Thank you! I'll stick with only jQuery method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the structured way.

```
    var childData = {
        apple: ["iPhone", "iPad"]  ,
        ms: ["Windows", "Office"]
    };
    $("#brand").change(function () {
        var newData = childData[this.value];
        var element = $("#model").empty();

        element.append('<option>----------------</option>');
        $.each(newData, function(i, val) {
            element.append('<option value='+i+'>'+val+'</option>');
        });

    });
```

Check this Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/w6E88/11/

Answer (score 1):

Using explicit conditionals to validate against will make this difficult to maintain in the future if the product line expands beyond a certain quantity.  Using some form of array is a better way to do it, as others have shown.

Also, while jQuery is a great library, don't forget about vanilla JavaScript.  When coded well, even though it appears more convoluted, plain JavaScript should run faster than a jQuery counterpart.  With that in mind, here's another solution, this time in "more or less" plain JavaScript -- I left in the on ready.

**HTML**

```
<select name="brand" id="brand">
  <option value="-1">--------------------</option>
  <option value="apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="microsoft">Microsoft</option>
</select>
<select id="model">
  <option value="-1">--------------------</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var products = {
  apple: [
    { name: "iPhone 6 Plus", model: "iphone_6plus" },
    { name: "iPhone 6", model: "iphone_6" },
    { name: "iPhone 5s", model: "iphone_5s" },
    { name: "iPhone 5c", model: "iphone_5c" }
  ],
  microsoft: [
    { name: "Windows 10", model: "windows_10" },
    { name: "Windows 8", model: "windows_8" },
    { name: "Office 2015", model: "office_2015" },
    { name: "Office 2014", model: "office_2014" }
  ]
};

function create_option(text, value) {
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  var txt = document.createTextNode(text);

  option.value = value;
  option.appendChild(txt);

  return option;
}

function populate_model(selection) {
  var select = document.getElementById("model");
  var i, l;

  if ((selection == -1) || (products[selection] === undefined))
    return false;

  while (select.lastChild)
    select.removeChild(select.lastChild);

  select.appendChild(document.createElement("option").appendChild(document.createTextNode("--------------------")));

  for (i = 0, l = products[selection].length; i < l; i++)
    select.appendChild(create_option(products[selection][i].name, products[selection][i].model));
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var brand = document.getElementById("brand");

  brand.onchange = function() {
    populate_model(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
  };

  brand.value = -1;
});
```

I've updated your JSFiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/w6E88/13/